# exclude array numbers for mysql

Tags: php

i have in mysql

```
id               = 1
id_bets          = 3
id_user          = 3
numbers_sell     = 4,7,9,1
```

I need in my php select all number for bets and exclue numbers sell

ex: bets have 50 numbers i nedd  show

2 3 5 8 10 11 12 etc.....
exlude - 4,7,9,1

my code

```
  for ($i=1; $i<=50; $i++) {
        $exclude = array(4,7,9,1);
        if(in_array($i, $exclude)) continue;
        echo $i;
    }
```

no work, array not accept while my sql

```
        $exclude = array($row['numbers_sell');
```

no work

Comment: In addition to Barmar's answer below, consider https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `explode()` to split up the value from the table column.

```
$exclude = explode(',', $row['numbers_sell']);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243695/discussion-on-answer-by-barmar-exclude-array-numbers-for-mysql).